# Repeating transitionWithView with UIImage Not Working

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, uiimage, transition

I am trying to animate the change of an UIImageView's image using **transitionWithView**.

```
     func updateImage() {             
        let newImage = UIImage(CIImage: self.myImage)
        UIView.transitionWithView(self.myImageView!,
                         duration: 0.5,
                          options: [UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionCrossDissolve],
                       animations: {

              self.myImageView?.image = newImage

        }, completion: {
              finished in
              self.performSelector(#selector(self.updateImage), withObject: nil, afterDelay: 1)
        })
     }
```

### Issue

It animate the fade properly only the first time.  From second time on, it's an abrupt change without cross fade animation.

### What I've tried

I tried changing transition style from 'cross dissolve' to 'flip', then it shows flip animation every time.  Only on cross dissolve, first time only....